# Создание именованного канала С++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Прочитал, что это делается так: (Исключая различные проверки на отсутствие экземпляра и прочее)

```
char *pipename = "\\\\.\\pipe\\namedpipe";
HANDLE hPipe;

hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipename,PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |PIPE_WAIT,PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,4096,4096,0,NULL);
```

И тут, чего я в принципе ожидал вылазит ошибка. Первый параметр - имя канала, который у меня pipename в прототипе функции указан как LPTWSTR, вот компилятор и пишет:

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [22]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Вопрос, что делать, напрямую указать имя, не через переменную тоже не удается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
wchar_t *pipename = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\namedpipe";
```

---

Если для вас всё ещё актуальны ANSI-версии кода, возможно, лучше написать

```
TCHAR *pipename = _T("\\\\.\\pipe\\namedpipe");
```

Но в принципе на сегодняшний день лучше не заморачиваться с ANSI-версиями, и писать только на Unicode.

Comment: Спасибо) Что за тип wchar_t? и зачем L перед кавычками?

Comment: wchar_t -- это 16-битный символ Unicode. L в начале строки означает, что строка не из обычных, а из 16-битных символов.

Comment: Спасибо) ____

Comment: @BlackOverlord: Пожалуйста!